# Read temperature from nRF 51822 with sensor HTS221 via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to read temperature from this little sensor https://www.aliexpress.com/item/temperature-sensor-and-humidity-sensor-HTS221/32953862359.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.e3534c4dT9GRz3

```
There are 4 GattServices available
GattService 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb - Generic Access
here are characteristics: 
00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Device Name
00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Appearance
00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters

GattService 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb - Generic Attribute
no characteristics
GattService 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb - Device Information
here is characteristic:
00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Manufacturer Name String
GattService 6e400000-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e - ???
```

It looks that HTS221 is not sending data by default, what should I do to be able to read the temperature ?